# AS3: Cannot call a function in class

Tags: function, class, oop, actionscript-3, call

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this doesn't work. I'm trying to call a function from the document class that is found inside of an instance of a MovieClip.

In the document class I have:

```
import com.BudgetSettings;
showSettings();

function showSettings():void
{
    var settings:BudgetSettings = new BudgetSettings;
    addChild(settings);
    settings.addListeners();
}
```

Then in the BudgetSettings class I have:

```
package com {

    public class BudgetSettings extends MovieClip
    {
        public function BudgetSettings():void
        {
            //constructor code
        }

        public function addListeners():void
        {
            trace("got here");
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like a routine call to a function inside of a class instance, but it produces Error #1006: addListeners is not a function. I tried creating other functions as well, and the same error is produced.

It seems as if the class instance is created and placed on the stage just fine, but any methods inside of it cannot be called from the document class. I double checked, and the path to the class is correct.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: If you put **trace** into the **BudgetSettings** constructor, does it trace?

Comment: Great question. Nothing in the constructor seems to execute, even a trace.

Comment: That means your class is not compiled into your app (even if you double checked), then Flash creates a substitute empty class **com.BudgetSettings** for your Library symbol which does not have **addListeners** method. Check again. Your class must be in the **com** folder then **BudgetSettings.as** file from any folder which is a source folder for your **FLA** file (File > Publish Settings > ActionScript 3 Settings > Source Folders).

Comment: Brilliant answer, Organis! I was not aware that Flash created an empty class, but this explains why the error was at runtime rather than when compiling. I added the folder as you suggested and a new error presented itself: "the name of package 'com' does not reflect the location of this file..." I ended up deleting the word 'com' after package in the class and it worked. Odd, since I assumed it needed that bit to resolve the correct path, but regardless, it worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this entry, I should add that I was using Adobe Air 26 for iOS. The folder I had to add was in the ActionScript 3.0 settings (which was in addition to the folder already having been added to the Air 26.0 for iOS settings)

Comment: If you have, for example, a class **com.graph.PieChart**, that means it should reside at **com/graph/PieChart.as** file where **com/graph** is the folder structure that starts from any folder that is source folder for your project. In the Library properties panel there is a check button next to the class name that produces an alerts with texts "class WAS found" or "class WAS NOT found" respective to the result. Stay alert as otherwise both alerts are very similar.

Comment: Yes, BudgetSettings.as resides in the 'com' folder along with a bunch of other classes (like Greensock). So: com/BudgetSettings.as. It surprised me "package com { }" did not work, but "package { }" did.

I did not expect the document class to find the object class without specifying the enclosing 'com' folder. I've created lots of classes and can't remember writing it that way, but its working, so I'm happy.

I'll keep that in mind about the WAS/WAS NOT found in the Library, that'll save me a hassle next time and is a great way to check if things are in order. Thanks again!